# Cummulative spacing after runsubsection

Tags: spacing, templates, deedy-resume

I'm new to Latex and I'm adapting [Deedy resume template](https://github.com/deedy/Deedy-Resume) trying to add dots joined by lines to spot dates using Tikz. After each `\runsubsection` command nodes are placed after vertical spacing that appears to be linear to the current subsection number.

The code is showing node borders in order to show the problem. I'm attaching an image with the spacing marked with a red ellipse.

[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,backgrounds,positioning}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\begin{document}

\namesection{doo}{bar}{ \urlstyle{same}\href{https://foo} \\
}


\section{Section}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

%n0
%\tikz[baseline] \node[circle,label=left:label,fill=black,inner sep=3pt] (n0) at (,0)  {};
\tikz[baseline] \node[draw,fill=none,align=left] at (,0)  {
  \vbox{
    \runsubsection{runsubsection}\descript{| descript }
  }
};
\tikz[baseline] \node[draw,fill=none,align=left] at (,0)  {
  \hspace*{15mm}\vbox{
    \blindtext
  }
};

%n1
%\tikz[baseline] \node[circle,label=left:label,fill=black,inner sep=3pt] (n1) at (,1)  {};
\tikz[baseline] \node[draw,fill=none,align=left] at (,1)  {
  \vbox{
    \runsubsection{runsubsection}\descript{| descript }
  }
};
\tikz[baseline] \node[draw,fill=none,align=left] at (,0)  {
  \hspace*{15mm}\vbox{
    \blindtext
  }
};

%n2    
%\tikz[baseline] \node[circle,label=left:label,fill=black,inner sep=3pt] (n2) at (,2)  {};
\tikz[baseline] \node[draw,fill=none,align=left] at (,2)  {
  \vbox{
    \runsubsection{runsubsection}\descript{| descript }
  }
};
\tikz[baseline] \node[draw,fill=none,align=left] at (,0)  {
  \hspace*{15mm}\vbox{
    \blindtext
  }
};

%n3
%\tikz[baseline] \node[circle,label=left:label,fill=black,inner sep=3pt] (n3) at (,3)  {};
\tikz[baseline] \node[draw,fill=none,align=left] at (,3)  {
  \vbox{
    \runsubsection{runsubsection}\descript{| descript }
  }
};
\tikz[baseline] \node[draw,fill=none,align=left] at (,0)  {
  \hspace*{15mm}\vbox{
    \blindtext
  }
};

\sectionsep
\end{document}  \documentclass[]{article}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks, Marmot! I have updated the code and the image.

Comment: Please remove `\documentclass[]{article}` in the end. (Unfortunately I cannot help you since I do not have the document class and do not follow external links. What strikes me odd, though are all the missing `x` coordinates as in `at (,0)`, I've not seen that before in a working code.)

Comment: You have been taken in by a common misconception.  What is referred to on the internet as “LaTeX templates” are in reality **other people's documents** which are tailored to their *specific* needs.  Therefore it is close to **impossible to perform any modifications** on these without breaking the entire thing.  They are really only meant to exchange their content with yours.  Any other adjustment is simply out of scope.

Comment: Thanks again @Marmot, I am generating my latex with an erb template and I added a bug when I was trimming it for this questions. I have added a link to overleaf to show the problem.

Comment: Maybe `\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]` is changing of value every time we have a `remember picture`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `\node[...] at (0,0)` everywhere (or leave out `at (0,0)` altogether)

```
\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,backgrounds,positioning}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\begin{document}

\namesection{doo}{bar}{ \urlstyle{same}\href{https://foo} \\
}


\section{Section}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

%n0
%\tikz[baseline] \node[circle,label=left:label,fill=black,inner sep=3pt] (n0) at (,0)  {};
\tikz[baseline] \node[draw,fill=none,align=left] at (0,0)  {
  \vbox{
    \runsubsection{runsubsection}\descript{| descript }
  }
};
\tikz[baseline] \node[draw,fill=none,align=left] at (0,0)  {
  \hspace*{15mm}\vbox{
    \blindtext
  }
};

%n1
%\tikz[baseline] \node[circle,label=left:label,fill=black,inner sep=3pt] (n1) at (,1)  {};
\tikz[baseline] \node[draw,fill=none,align=left] at (0,0)  {
  \vbox{
    \runsubsection{runsubsection}\descript{| descript }
  }
};
\tikz[baseline] \node[draw,fill=none,align=left] at (0,0)  {
  \hspace*{15mm}\vbox{
    \blindtext
  }
};

%n2    
%\tikz[baseline] \node[circle,label=left:label,fill=black,inner sep=3pt] (n2) at (,2)  {};
\tikz[baseline] \node[draw,fill=none,align=left] at (0,0)  {
  \vbox{
    \runsubsection{runsubsection}\descript{| descript }
  }
};
\tikz[baseline] \node[draw,fill=none,align=left] at (0,0)  {
  \hspace*{15mm}\vbox{
    \blindtext
  }
};

%n3
%\tikz[baseline] \node[circle,label=left:label,fill=black,inner sep=3pt] (n3) at (,3)  {};
\tikz[baseline] \node[draw,fill=none,align=left] at (0,0)  {
  \vbox{
    \runsubsection{runsubsection}\descript{| descript }
  }
};
\tikz[baseline] \node[draw,fill=none,align=left] at (0,0)  {
  \hspace*{15mm}\vbox{
    \blindtext
  }
};

\sectionsep
\end{document}
```

[Live example on Overleaf](https://v1.overleaf.com/read/nmvfdrvqqvrb)

Comment: Nice tool. I have cloned your project to show my problem when I try to join nodes with lines: https://v1.overleaf.com/22634957hydkptwgmmyn#/74549583/

Comment: @Rod Why aren't you doing as I suggested in the answer and set `at (0,0)` *for all the nodes*? https://v1.overleaf.com/read/bjsttjywtkcr

Comment: I have done it and it is almost finished, thanks for your support @Henri. Just one misalignment in the line "some problem HERE!". By any chance do you know what's the issue there?

Comment: @Rod `\location{some problem HERE!}\par\vspace{\topsep}` It's always fun using this “template” garbage.